# Block identity theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $C$ and $C'$ represent the matrix of a linear transformation with respect distinct bases then we know $C$ and $C'$ are equivalent; in particular we can find invertible matrices $A$ and $B$ such $C'=BCA$. Can we also conclude that $C'$ can be taken to have a partial identity block form? that is an identity block (consisting of only ones) of some size and $0's$ in the remaining entries? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer emphasizing the linear transformation aspect rather than the matrix aspect.  Suppose $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation.  Let $K_0$ be a basis for its kernel; since that's a linearly independent set in $V$, it can be extended to a basis $K$ for $V$.  The images under $T$ of the vectors in $K\setminus K_0$ form a linearly independent set $L_0$ in $W$; extend it to  basis $L$ of $W$.  Then the matrix of $T$ with respect to the the bases $K$ and $L$ consists of an identity matrix in the block indexed by $K\setminus K_0$ and $L_0$, and zeros in all other entries.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use elementary row operations to bring $C$ to its *reduced* row echelon form $R$, then use elementary column operations to bring $R$ to its reduced column echelon form $C'$.